# codeigniter encryption_key same for multiple config.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I submit my form it writes a config.php file for codeigniter and inserts a `substr(md5(uniqid(), true)), 0, 32)` into encryption_key.

I write two config.php files at same time for different applications.

When the encryption_key is generated it creates a uniqid for each one.

The question I have is it possible to make it so when the form submitted it creates the same key for both. How to modify this `substr(md5(uniqid(), true)), 0, 32)`

Comment: Just assign the result to a variable and use that in both places...?

Comment: You mean some thing like `$salt = substr(md5(uniqid(), true)), 0, 32)` variable `$salt`